# Python calling method from different class

Tags: python, oop

Let's suppose I have 2 classes "Task" and "Day". Task will have the name of the task, and then by "add_task" you can have multiple occurrences of the same task (say swimming 3 times a week). How would I make the class "DAY" (say monday) to check if there is a conflict between two tasks in the same time slot?

```
 class Task(object):
        def __init__(self,name,type):
            self.name = name
            self.type = type
            self.instances = 0
            self.start = 0
            self.end = 0
            self.total_time = []

           def add_task(self,day,start,end):
        self.day = day
        monday.add_new_task(self,start,end)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.instances += 1
        self.total_time += [start,end]



class Day(object):
    time_available = []
    check_time = []
    def __init__ (self):
        for i in range(24):
            self.time_available.append(i)
    def add_new_task (self,start,end):
        print start
        print end
        if self.time_available.__contains__(self,start):
            print "Contains"
```

The logic for add_new_task is simplified but that is the general idea.
I am new to python so syntax is something I am getting acquainted with.

Comment: What is the representation of the "time"?  Is it time-of-day-in-seconds?

Comment: time is in hours, and is a "segment" for example 14-16, keeping it simple for now

Comment: you title  doesn't seem to be relevant. what you need is an interval tree if i understand it correctly.

Comment: do you mean conflicts between tasks on the same day or conflicts between tasks on different days? Provide more details and examples

Comment: conflicts on the same day. Ex: Swimming 12-14 would be a conflict with Soccer 13-15.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to address this problem you need to use a class variable that is a variable defined inside a class and outside the class methods. In the following example, `time` is a class variable of class `Day`; you can have access to the class variable i.e. `time` as `Day.time`.

The class variable is somehow independent of the class instances. For example, suppose that `d` is an instance of `Day`, there is a subtle but important difference between `d.time` and `Day.time`. The following example helps you to understand it.

```
class Day(object):
    """docstring for Day"""
    time = {'name':'Allen'}
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg


class Task(object):
    """docstring for Task"""
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

print Day.time # Prints {'name': 'Allen'}
d = Day(10)
d.time = 12
print d.time  # Prints 12
print Day.time  # Prints {'name': 'Allen'}
```

You may find more about the class variables and instance variables [here](https://timothyawiseman.wordpress.com/2012/10/06/class-and-instance-variables-in-python-2-7/).

Comment: I have edited my code^ showing what I am trying to do, its giving syntax errors and I have a feeling I'm doing something really wrong, but that's what I am trying to get at.

Comment: Obviously there is an indentation error. The other error is that you try to access the class variable using `self`.

Comment: `self.time_available` is an instance variable, replace it with `Day.time_available`